# Setuptools, explicitely separate multiple commands calls in one line

Tags: python, setuptools

I would like to write an alias in my setup.py file to multiple tests commands for my project.

But, I have problems when I try to run multiple commands on one line, when 'nosetests' command is invoked before other commands.

This works

```
$ python setup.py lint nosetests
pylint output
nosetests output
```

But if I exchange the commands, I only gets `nosetests` output.

I think the `lint` command is eaten by the nosetests argument parser.

```
$ python setup.py nosetests lint
nosetests output
# No pylint output
```

So, I would like to know if there is a way to explicitly separate the commands ?

Thanks

Comment: To keep your `setup.py` more declarative; you could offload imperative tasks to [`paver`](http://paver.github.io/paver/) and/or [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New answer**

By the looks of it, `setuptools` assumes all options begin with `--` and all commands don't begin with `--`, so there's no explicit way to separate commands, because it's unnecessary.

If the custom `nosetests` command is accepting `lint` as an option, then it's a bug in that command, which ought to ignore anything which doesn't begin with `--`.

However, it might be possible to work around the bug with the traditional Unix idiom of using `--` to indicate the end of options, so the following might work...

```
$ python setup.py nosetests -- lint
```

...otherwise you'll either have to fix the bug, or find an alternative to using that particular custom command.

**Old answer**

From [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#using-setup-py)...

> The basic usage of `setup.py` is:
>
> `$ python setup.py <some_command> <options>`

...so it sounds like the fact that it executed both commands on your first example is a bug, or a fluke.

It's probably safest to run them as two separate commands...

```
$ python setup.py nosetests && python setup.py lint
nosetests output
pylint output
```

Comment: If you look at the result of the `python setup.py --help-commands` in the documentation, the 'usage' line says:
    `usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]`

Comment: And the description of the 'alias' commands says `define a shortcut to invoke one **or more** commands`. So multiple commands should be allowed. I would like to have an alias which runs several commands instead of a bash script.

Comment: @cladmi Can you include the contents of your `setup.py` in the original question?

Comment: I already tried '--' to separate without success.
So it's what I was expecting, the setuptools command 'nosetests' is buggy, and there is no miracle solution.